# Proof integral converging : $\int \sin ( \sin (x) )dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> I need to find either those two integrals converges or not :
>
> $$\int_0^\infty \sin ( \sin (x) )dx$$ $$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sin (
> \sin (x) )} xdx$$
>
> I don't want a proof that computes the integral ! (if it is possible
>   in anyway, I don't know if it is even possible).

---

There are some suggestions. I'll show you i've done :

**My attemps :**

- *For the first one, I told that we know :
  If the infinite sum of a sequence converges, then the sequence converges to zero. Thus, it is the same for the integral. Here, since $\sin (
  \sin (x) )$ does not have any limit at infinity, the integral can't be defined properly.*

What do you think of my attemp? If it is okay, do you have any other idea to solve my problem?

- Then, a second proof, following the suggestion :

$$ k \in \mathbb Z, \, x \in [  - \frac \pi 2 + 2 k \pi, \frac \pi 2 + 2 k \pi]  : \, \ | \frac {x- 2k \pi }{2} | \leq | sin(x) | \leq | x - 2k \pi |   $$
But then I don't know what to do... I thought that  maybe we can use the squeeze theorem but I don't know how from there...

[image]

- Finally for the second integral, I have no clue at all... I was suggested to compare the integral for $x$ and for $x+\pi$ and actually :

$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\sin (
\sin (x + \pi) )} { x + \pi } dx = \int_0^\infty  -\frac{\sin (
\sin (x) )} { x + \pi } dx $$

thank you for reading me :)

Comment: The first doesn't converge, the second does.

Comment: that's also what I think, but why?

Comment: The first behaves like a sin, thus the area below the line oscillates like a cos. It has no limit. The second behaves like an $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}$, thus it converges. These are only my intuitive impressions and they are not correct, axiomatical reasonings, this is why I give a comment and not an answer. Hopefully others will give you full answers, too.

Comment: I see that it behaves like a sin but why ? I was not sure why... You have that $-1 < sin x < 1 $ but then, what about $ sin(sin(x)) $?

Comment: Sin is zero in zero, and it becomes 1 roughly at 1.5 (half pi). Around zero, it is nearly linear. Thus, sin sin oscillates between sin 1 and sin -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(t)=\int_0^t\sin(\sin(x))$.
You have $\sin(\sin(x))\geq 0$ for all $0\leq x\leq\pi$ hence $a:=F(\pi)>0$.
Since $x\mapsto\sin(\sin(x))$ is odd and $2\pi$-periodic we have
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\sin(x))dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(\sin(x))dx=0$$
and
$$F(n\pi)=\int_0^{n\pi}\sin(\sin(x))dx=
\begin{cases}
a&2\nmid n\\
0&2\mid n
\end{cases}$$
hence cannot converge for $n\to\infty$.

Since $F(2n\pi)=0$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ and since $F$ is bounded, integration by parts yelds for $n>0$
$$\left|\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}xdx\right|
=\left|\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{F(x)}{x^2}\right|
\leq\frac{\sup|F|}{2\pi n^2}$$
Consequently,
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}xdx=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}xdx+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}xdx$$
converges because $\sin (\sin (x))\sim x $ for $x\to 0$.

Comment: In somehow, you just proved that the sequence $\left(\int_0^{2n\pi}\frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,\mathrm d x\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges, not that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\sin(x))}{x}\,\mathrm d x$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin\sin x$ is a smooth and periodic function with mean zero, hence $\int_{0}^{M}\sin\sin(x)\,dx$ is bounded but it is not convergent as $M\to +\infty$. On the other hand [Kronecker's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma) (or just integration by parts) ensures that $\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{M}\sin\sin(x)\frac{dx}{x}$ **is** convergent. By expanding $\sin\sin(x)$ as a Fourier sine series we have

$$ \sin\sin(x) = 2 J_1(1)\sin(x) + 2 J_3(1)\sin(3x) + 2J_5(1) \sin(5x)+\ldots $$
with $J_n$ being a [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html). We have $0\leq J_n(1)\leq \frac{1}{2^n n!}$ and 
$$\lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{M}\frac{\sin(mx)}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
for any $m\in\mathbb{N}^+$, hence the identity
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin\sin(x)}{x}\,dx = \pi\sum_{m\geq 0}J_{2m+1}(1) $$
provides an efficient numerical computation of the LHS, which is $\approx 1.44470914981$.